# Solidity: float causes funds that are stuck on the contract

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I'm making my own contract which pays out tokens to its members depending of their shares amount. To calculate payment I'm using the following formula:

```
function calculatePaymentValue(
    uint pRawPaymentValue,
    uint pSharesTotal
)
    public
    pure
    returns (uint256 l_paymentPerShare, uint256 l_paymentRealValue)
{
    l_paymentPerShare = pRawPaymentValue * 15 / pSharesTotal;
    l_paymentRealValue = l_paymentPerShare * pSharesTotal / 15;

}
```

Raw payment means the total amount of new tokens that got transferred to the contract.

Payment real value is done to avoid A LOT OF permanently stuck tokens on the contract.

And for the pending tokens:

```
function _pending(
    uint256 pShares,
    uint256 pLastPaymentPerShare,
    uint256 pMemberPending
) internal view returns (uint256) {
    (bool l_canUpdate, uint256 l_paymentPerShare, , ) = _calcUpdate(
        _paymentPerShare,
        _sharesTotal,
        _payment
    );
    require(l_canUpdate, "Cannot get update data");
    return pShares * (l_paymentPerShare - pLastPaymentPerShare) / 15 + pMemberPending;
}
```

The code works well but if I follow the following example:

1. Payment set: 1e18
2. Mark: 100 * 1e10 shares
3. Alice: 100 * 1e11 shares
4. Mark receives payment
5. Alice receives payment

The result will be 1 stuck token on the contract.

At first I was concerned and I had no idea why is that happening but I wrote it down how it seems to work and it's like the following:

> Mark_shares: 100 * 1e10 = 1000000000000

> Alice_shares: 100 * 1e11 = 10000000000000

> shares_sum: 100 * 1e10 + 100 * 1e11 = 11000000000000

> divider: 15

> payment: 1e18

> payment_per_share: payment * divider / shares_sum =  1e18 * 15 / 11000000000000 = 1363636,36363636363636363636 = 1363636

> real payment: payment_per_share * shares_sum / divider = 1363636 * 11000000000000 / 15 = 999999733333333333,33333333333333333333 = 999999733333333333

> Mark_reward: Mark_shares * payment_per_share / divider = 100 * 1e10 * 1363636 / 15 = 90909066666666666,66666666666666666667 = 909090666666666666

> Alice_reward: Alice_shares * payment_per_share / divider = 100 * 1e11 * 1363636 / 15 = 909090666666666666,66666666666666666667 = 90909066666666666

> reward_sum = Mark_reward + Alice_reward = 909090666666666666 + 90909066666666666 = 999999733333333332

> stuck: real payment - reward_sum = 999999733333333333 - 999999733333333332 = 1

It seems to be logic and probably I found the issue but still don't know any solution how to fix it.

If I put random accounts with random shares amounts and random payment, every payment and withdraw loop adds between 0 and 10 stuck tokens.

I found a bypass of this issue - If I remove the divider (15) from the code everything seems to be working correctly but if I give 100 * 1e18 amount of shares to a member with 1e18 payment the entire withdrawal is broken, noone is able to withdraw funds. You could say ok, so just remove the divider and set shares limit and it will work, yes, for mere shares I can do that, but if I change shares to a token deposit it will still cause issues if someone deposits 100 * 1e18 tokens.

How can I solve this problem in Solidity?

Comment: It is something that will always happen when you have to split an integer into fractional parts. One option is to keep the remainder for the next round. Another option is to accumulate the fractional parts between rounds.

Comment: How can I make it possible to store the remainder in the code to put it into the next round?

Comment: Calculate the sum of every participant share, that will be how much will be paid. Then you can subtract it from the total available to get the unclaimable remainder.

Comment: In theory is's simple, in practice it would be impossible to do because number of participants can be dynamic, because anyone can deposit (become participant) or withdraw (renounce the participation). Iterating through eg. 20,000 participants would cause out of gas.

Comment: You hadn't mentioned those conditions before. I've seen some project use more decimal places 30, 40, etc. and accumulate shares by address. The problem is that the EVM has a finite number of digits, so there won't be a perfect solution. You will have to choose what is best for your situation.